# Execute PHP script on FTP server connected to in another local PHP script

Tags: php, ftp

is it possible to execute a php script on the server when connecting it. (not on the server, which builds the connection)?

```
<?php
// set up basic connection
$ftp_server = "localhost";
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$ftp_user_name = "myuser";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypass";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
        echo "FTP connection has failed!";
        echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
    }

$buff = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, '../ftpdest/index.php?action=download_now');
var_dump($buff);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

*Some*, but not many, FTP servers support `SITE EXEC command` that allows you to execute arbitrary or selected shell commands on the server. The command can be remote `php` binary.

In PHP, you can use [`ftp_site` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-site.php) for that:

```
ftp_site($conn_id, "EXEC php -r \"echo 'Hello world!';\"");
```

But this will probably not work with your server. In most cases, you won't be able to execute a shell command over FTP.

---

If your FTP server is actually a web server, you can use FTP to upload a PHP script and then use the web server to execute the script.

```
ftp_put($conn_id, "/httpdocs/script.php", "/local/path/script.php");
file_get_contents("https://example.com/script.php");
```

---

If you have an SSH/shell access, use the SSH to execute your PHP script/code. The SSH is an API designed for executing script/code (contrary to FTP).